# JQuery - after() function with quotes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, jquery-after

I need to add some HTML after a radio-button, I want to add an image and function so I check the radio button when I click on it. I would check the radio button with my own `selectRadioButton()` function.

The existing code is, I **can't** edit this part:

```
<span class="ms-RadioText">
  <input id="idFirstRadioButton" type="radio" name="idFirstRadioButton" value="1" />
</span>
```

My idea, to add my image with function, was to do it like this:

```
$("#idFirstRadioButton").after("Image 1:<br/><a href=\"javascript:selectRadioButton(\"idFirstRadioButton\")\"><img src=\"http://urltoimage/image.jpg\" border=\"0\"/></a>");
```

But when I use this code, the HTML of my page is this:

```
<span class="ms-RadioText">
  <input id="idFirstRadioButton" type="radio" name="idFirstRadioButton" value="1" /> Image 1:<br/><a href="javascript:selectRadioButton(" shape="" idFirstRadioButton?)?=""><IMG src="http://urltoimage/image.jpg" border=0></a>
</span>
```

He's adding "shape="" idFirstRadioButton?)?="""

The correct code should be:

```
<span class="ms-RadioText">
   <input id="idFirstRadioButton" type="radio" name="idFirstRadioButton" value="1" /> Image 1:<br/><a href="javascript:selectRadioButton("idFirstRadioButton")><IMG src="http://urltoimage/image.jpg" border=0></a>
</span>
```

I already tried with `'`, with `\"`, combination of both, with a variable, ...

```
$("#idFirstRadioButton").after("Image 1:<br/><a href=\"javascript:selectRadioButton(\"idFirstRadioButton\")\"><img src=\"http://urltoimage/image.jpg\" border=\"0\"/></a>");
$("#idFirstRadioButton").after('Image 1:<br/><a href="javascript:selectRadioButton(\"idFirstRadioButton\")"><img src="http://urltoimage/image.jpg" border="0"/></a>');
$("#idFirstRadioButton").after('Image 1:<br/><a href="javascript:selectRadioButton("' + VARidFirstRadioButton + '")"><img src="http://urltoimage/image.jpg" border="0"/></a>');
```

What am I doing wrong or what is the code that I should use?

Comment: _“The correct code should be:”_ – no, it should not. You should not use HTML attributes to bind event handlers in the first place, but the way jQuery provides for that (.on)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you're doing wrong is using strings of HTML instead of constructing and appending Elements themselves, which (in addition to potential security concerns) can lead to the sort of confusing and annoying behavior you're seeing here.  You want something like this:

```
var myImg = $("<img/>");
myImg.attr("src", "http://urltoimage/image.jpg");
myImg.on("click", function(e) {
  selectRadioButton("idFirstRadioButton");
});
$("#idFirstRadioButton").after(myImg);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use different quotes inside your `.after` string, because they will be required. For example:

```
$("#idFirstRadioButton").after("Image 1:<br/><a href=\"javascript:selectRadioButton('idFirstRadioButton')\"><img src=\"http://urltoimage/image.jpg\" border=\"0\"/></a>");
```

This is the result:

```
<a href="javascript:selectRadioButton('idFirstRadioButton')"><img src="http://urltoimage/image.jpg" border="0"></a>
```

However, this is only if you have no other option. As @CBroe mentioned, you should try not to bind event handlers inside appended html, but try to handle them using proper way.
Example @Dan O provided seems to be something you should be looking for.

Answer (score 0):

When you have more than 1 level deep of `"` or `'` you need to intercalate them or escape them.

The last one should be right, except you kept using  `"` inside instead of escaping them or alternating them.

The correct should be:

```
$("#idFirstRadioButton").after('Image 1:<br/><a href="javascript:selectRadioButton(\'' + VARidFirstRadioButton + '\')"><img src="http://urltoimage/image.jpg" border="0"/></a>');
```

So we start with single quote for the after, then double quote for the href, then we escape a single quote for the inside of the selectRadioButton, then a single quote to exit the string and dump the `var`, then back inside the string and keep going on.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/383p6h0h/)

> NOTE: Remember to declare your var "VARidFirstRadioButton" that's the
>   `shape of` error.